# Gulp Uglify problems with $super global in Prototype

Tags: gulp, prototype, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to use gulp-uglify to compress and uglify all JS files recursively in my directory:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: {reserved: '$super'}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js_dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compress']);
```

This works okay, but I noticed javascript errors throughout my website. This is because in the [Prototype file](http://view-source:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js) I can see just one occurrence of `$super` in quotes on line 138 still remains, but the other 12 occurrences of it have been uglified. I thought that the `reserved` section would reserve this global, but it doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly enough, formatting the code like this solved my problem:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify({
            'mangle': {
                reserved: ['$super']
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js_dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compress']);
```

Comment: Not that weird, mangle.reserved takes an array of values https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangle-options even if it is only one value.

Comment: I realised that soon after. All is working perfectly now!